# Rails 4 - Displaying a Users Search Results to a View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm using the Spotify API and am trying display search results for an artist on the same view page that the search form is on.  I think I'm close but just need a little bit of help.  Rails noob obviously..

How do I set the url `http://localhost:3000/search?query=what_do_i_set_this_to???` to the user input I'm trying to collect via this line in my search form `<%= text_field_tag(:query, "", class: 'form-control', autofocus: true, placeholder: "Enter artist name") %>`

Much thanks in advance!  I've been stuck on this for about a week now.

**UPDATE** (what my code currently looks like now)

**Controller**

artists_controller.rb

```
class ArtistsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    request = search_params[:query]
    unless request.nil?
      response = HTTParty.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q="+request+"&type=artist")
      @hash_version = JSON.parse(response.body)
    end
  end

  private

  def search_params
    params.permit(:query, :utf8, :commit)
  end
end
```

**View**

artists/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Artist Search</h1>
<i>(search for artists you would like to follow)</i>
<br>
<br>
<%= form_tag(artists_path, method: :get) do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag(:query, "Search artist by name:") %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:query, params[:query], class: 'form-control', autofocus: true, placeholder: "Enter artist name") %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= submit_tag("Search", class: 'btn btn-success') %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<% @hash_version["artists"]["items"].each_with_index do |band, index| %>
  <% if index == @hash_version["artists"]["items"].size - 1 %>
    <li class="artist_li">
      <%= image_tag(band["images"].first["url"], class: 'img-responsive artist_img') rescue image_tag("microphone.png", class: 'img-responsive artist_img mic_bg') %>
      <br>
      <h1 class="artist_name"><%= band["name"] %></h1>
      <br>
      <% if band["genres"].empty? %>
        <h5>no genres</h5>
      <% else %>
        <h5><%= band["genres"] %></h5>
      <% end %>
      <br>
      <h5><%= band["followers"]["total"] %> followers</h5>
      <br>
      <h4>(Follow)</h4>
      <!-- no hr with last li -->
    </li>
  <% else %>
    <li class="artist_li">
      <%= image_tag(band["images"].first["url"], class: 'img-responsive artist_img') rescue image_tag("microphone.png", class: 'img-responsive artist_img mic_bg') %>
      <br>
      <h1 class="artist_name"><%= band["name"] %></h1>
      <br>
      <% if band["genres"].empty? %>
        <h5>no genres</h5>
      <% else %>
        <h5><%= band["genres"] %></h5>
      <% end %>
      <br>
      <h5><%= band["followers"]["total"] %> followers</h5>
      <br>
      <h4>(Follow)</h4>
      <hr class="artists_hr">
    </li>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should us the name option and passing it in the value option as params[:query] as follow :

```
<h1>Artist Search</h1>
<i>(search for artists you would like to follow)</i>
<br>
<br>
<%= form_tag(artists_path, method: :get) do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag(:query, "Search artist by name:") %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:query, params[:query], class: 'form-control', autofocus: true, placeholder: "Enter artist name") %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= submit_tag("Search", class: 'btn btn-success') %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<% unless @hash_version.nil? %>
<% @hash_version["artists"]["items"].each_with_index do |band, index| %>
  <% if index == @hash_version["artists"]["items"].size - 1 %>
    <li class="artist_li">
      <%= image_tag(band["images"].first["url"], class: 'img-responsive artist_img') rescue image_tag("microphone.png", class: 'img-responsive artist_img mic_bg') %>
      <br>
      <h1 class="artist_name"><%= band["name"] %></h1>
      <br>
      <% if band["genres"].empty? %>
        <h5>no genres</h5>
      <% else %>
        <h5><%= band["genres"] %></h5>
      <% end %>
      <br>
      <h5><%= band["followers"]["total"] %> followers</h5>
      <br>
      <h4>(Follow)</h4>
      <!-- no hr with last li -->
    </li>
  <% else %>
    <li class="artist_li">
      <%= image_tag(band["images"].first["url"], class: 'img-responsive artist_img') rescue image_tag("microphone.png", class: 'img-responsive artist_img mic_bg') %>
      <br>
      <h1 class="artist_name"><%= band["name"] %></h1>
      <br>
      <% if band["genres"].empty? %>
        <h5>no genres</h5>
      <% else %>
        <h5><%= band["genres"] %></h5>
      <% end %>
      <br>
      <h5><%= band["followers"]["total"] %> followers</h5>
      <br>
      <h4>(Follow)</h4>
      <hr class="artists_hr">
    </li>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

then in your controller just look for params[:query] and verify that it has some data before sending the request as follow :

```
class ArtistsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        request = search_params[:query]
        unless request.nil?
            response = HTTParty.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q="+request+"&type=artist")
            @hash_version = JSON.parse(response.body)
        end

    end

    private
    def search_params
        params.permit(:query, :utf8, :commit)
    end

end
```

and you should be good :)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  But where exactly do I pass in the params[:name] value?  I see from your example that you passed in params[:query] inside of the text_field_tag.  Also after trying your example, I'm left with an error: `NoMethodError in ArtistsController#index` `undefined method encoding' for nil:NilClass` pertaining to this line of code: `response = HTTParty.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=#{CGI.escape params[:query]}&type=artist")` which I think is because params[:query] is initially undefined when I first navigate to my search page.

Comment: name is an option the select_tag :) did you change your form as the example ? can you show your updated code ?

Comment: got the errors, first artists_path is a helper so if you use ", you convert it to string and rails doesn't convert it to the right url. also, before asking httparty to send a get request, you must make sure you have a request, if not, your code is going to try to convert the query anyway. finally and modified the controller to use strong parameter, and you should always do that for security reason. so check the modified code above and you should be good :)

Comment: Thanks so much for that follow up answer!  It almost works the way I want it to now.  Your solution works with the search results being displayed as `<h2><%= @hash_version %></h2>` in the view.  My only problem though is that when I iterate over the @hash_version instance variable I get a new error `NoMethodError in Artists#index` `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass` `<%= @hash_version["artists"]["items"].each_with_index do |band, index| %>`. How do I define []?  Updated code above.

Comment: You're very welcome :) The error above comes because you're not checking if @hash_version contain data before retrieving some action. I update the code above with a basic check :) checked it internally and it work.

Comment: Everything works fine now!  Thanks again for taking the time for walking me through it, much appreciated!  Now I just have to keep practicing :)

Comment: sure thing :) happy hacking !